# The entity type ApplicationRole is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, autofac, identity

I'm trying to integrate autofac into my WCF service.
I have an problem with Identity framework.
I can't add any users or roles cause have the exeption: The entity type [Name] is not part of the model for the current context.
I've registered types in Global.asax like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Service1>().SingleInstance();
builder.Register(c => new ApplicationContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString)).As<IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<ClientManager>().As<IClientManager>();
builder.RegisterType<IdentityUnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>();
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().As<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
builder.RegisterType<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>().As<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationRoleManager>().As<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();
builder.RegisterType<RoleStore<ApplicationRole>>().As<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string>>();
AutofacHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();
```

Then I resolve my UnitOfWork class:

```
var a = AutofacHostFactory.Container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
var role = new ApplicationRole { Name = "admin" };
a.RoleManager.Create(role);
```

After the last line I got the exeption.
What's wrong with my *"current contex"*?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I'm tried to add role to differnt dbContext with created ApllicationContext. 
I just did this:

`builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().As<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
builder.Register(c => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(c.Resolve<IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>>()))
    .As<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationRoleManager>().As<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();
builder.Register(c => new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(c.Resolve<IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>>()))
    .As<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string>>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();`